# Get Selected Value from Select2

Tags: jquery

I always get value from the **previous value** instead of **selected value from select2**. 
Here is my code:

```
$('.itemclass').on("select2:selecting", function (e) {
    alert($('.itemclass').select2().val());
});
```

Here is the Selection (I used select2). My last selection is 'ADDUAT_AE' and I select new item which is 'AMCAT_0807'.

[image: Selection]

But the problem is I always get the previous selected item.

[image]

HTML Code:

```
<div class="input-group">
     <select class="btn btn-default form-control itemclass" style="width: 100%;">
           <option>ADDUAT_AE</option>                                                         
           <option>AMC_AB</option>
           <option>AMCAT_0807</option>                                                                                                         
           <option>CSQT_AC</option>                                                            
           <option>ENK_EKA</option>                                                            
           <option>FIG6_B0905</option>
     </select>
<div class="input-group-btn">
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you include the html code or just replicate your code here?

Comment: Sorry I am not used in Jsfiddle. I included my HTML code. thanks -little_coder

Comment: in your select tag you have to add attribute multiple

Comment: @Sfili_81 why? I don't see anything regarding multiple selection in the OP request

Comment: Has i intended the OP i think he wants the 2 selected item or not?

Comment: I dont need to select multiple. i just need to select Selected value rather than Previous value. sorry suck at explaining things haha. but changing class, selecting > select or close works for me. Regardless thanks guys for sharing your thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".itemclass").select2();
$('.itemclass').on("select2:select", function (e) {
    alert($('.itemclass').select2().val());
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.12/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group">
     <select class="btn btn-default form-control itemclass" style="width: 100%;">
           <option>ADDUAT_AE</option>                                                         
           <option>AMC_AB</option>
           <option>AMCAT_0807</option>                                                                                                         
           <option>CSQT_AC</option>                                                            
           <option>ENK_EKA</option>                                                            
           <option>FIG6_B0905</option>
     </select>
<div class="input-group-btn">
```

select2:selecting method is Triggered before a result is selected.that's why value is not updated at that time.for more detail see official document  [https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events](http://%20https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events) 
you can use **select2:select** or **select2:close**

Comment: Thanks dude it works <3 sorry i cannot upvote. Low reputation, but thanks.

Comment: I only have 11 reputations. I still need 4 XD. but will upvote this later...

Please upvote this answer. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

```
alert($('.itemclass').select2().val())
```

This code block gives you the selected value do you need focused value?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation here: https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events

`select2:selecting - Triggered before a result is selected. This event can be prevented.`

This means it happens before actually doing the select. So, if you get the value on `:selecting` you get the value before the select.

You need: `select2:select` which is `Triggered whenever a result is selected.`

So your code will be:

```
$('.itemclass').on("select2:select", function (e) {
    alert($('.itemclass').select2().val());
});
```

Another option would be the one found in this answer which does not use the select2 events:
[select2 alert selected option when selecting the value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48364718/select2-alert-selected-option-when-selecting-the-value)

Comment: Glad it works. If it helped you can mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark under the votes number

Comment: Done, gonna upvote your answer if i gain reputation. XD thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace select2:selecting with **select2:close**.

```
$('.itemclass').on("select2:close", function (e) {
    alert($('.itemclass').select2().val());
});
```